# Adding 2 modules that exported from Unity for Android studio got Error : "Error: Program type already present: bitter.jnibridge.JNIBridge"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have android project in Kotlin in Android Studio and 2 unity modules(exported like project for android studio using Unity) that I wanna use in my project, but I got error "Error: Program type already present: bitter.jnibridge.JNIBridge"

I added two unity modules as libraries:

build.gradle (Module:app)

```
implementation project(path: ':module-unity-1')

implementation project(path: ':module-unity-2')
```

screen project structure:

[image: screen project structure]

Every exported module contains the same JAR archive :

screenshot JAR archive with the same classes:

[image: screenshot JAR archive with the same classes]

I can delete `JNIBridge`, but other classes have also the same names and problem not solving

I expect I can use 2 unity modules in one android project.

P.S. How I think, I can't configure exported project for Android Studio from Unity.

Comment: Hey, Did you able to find the solution for this?

Comment: @AyushMalviya I'm sorry, no

Comment: Hey, has anyone managed to find a fix for this?

Comment: Hey, are you able to fix this issue?