# Manifest merger failed when adding multiple unity game as library

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest, android-multidex

[image]

I have developed an android app and two unity game library modules imported from Unity, when including one module , the build is success. When including the second library, i am getting manifest merger errors.

In the app manifest , included `tools:replace="android:icon`,`android:theme"` but then also was unable to solve the issue.The error displays to add `tools:replace="android:value"`, I added in the app manifest also but the issue was not solved.

Can someone help me with this and where should I add
`tools:replace="android:value"` in app manifest or library manifest.

Comment: You can try and remove build id from one of your unity modules and see if that works.                                             <meta-data
            android:name="unity.build-id"
            android:value="88cf6226-6bf1-44f1-9bb1-0d6238e78821" />.

Comment: @AyushMalviya I tried the above the next error occurred, since both my unity modules contains same jar file i am getting this error   

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178182/adding-2-modules-that-exported-from-unity-for-android-studio-got-error-error

Comment: @AyushMalviya To Solve the above error I imported the jar files in a separate module and removed from the libs folder of two unity modules. Now i added the jar files module as a dependancy to both the unity modules . Now run time error occurred like this 

**more than one file was found with os independent path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libmain.so'**

Comment: @GokulRajkumar were you able to resolve the issue ?

Comment: @user3551029 No I was not able to resolve the issue. We merged two games into one unity package and exported it as single android module and proceeded

Answer (score 0):

This issue you can solve after removing the below code from the UnityLibrary.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="unity.build-id"
        android:value="69350629-5d65-481f-9bc0-75e537719941" />
```

This code exist into your AndroidManifest.xml file for unityLibrary. And after doing this. Again follow the complete process.